# how to access each widget individually in flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget

I have a N*M rectangular grid of custom stateful widgets (cells) with which the user interacts by clicking and after the user selects all required cells - there is a background N*M array (Array) which updates in meantime then he clicks a button and then depending on the N*M Array some code will run and modifies the Array cell by cell.

Now i want to output the cell by cell transition in the N*M grid widget.

More specifically, there will be a plain maze grid and the user places an obstacle at each cell he presses on then he hits findPath method for each step in the findPath method i need to show the transition in the maze grid.

i finished taking the input from the user and have the findPath method but unable to show the output onto the maze grid for each step.

code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '2darray.dart';

int rowNum = 10;
int colNum = 10;
gridClass playArea ;
void main() {
  playArea = new gridClass(rowNum,colNum);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text(
       'this is title',
         style: TextStyle(
           backgroundColor: Colors.purple[600],
            fontSize: 20.0,
             fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black,
         ),
       ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple[700],
      ),
   body: Center(
      child: new GridDisplay(), 
        ),
       ),
      ));
     }


   int currNodeValue = 0;

    class node extends StatefulWidget { // this is the cell stateful 
                               //custom widget
  int nodeRow , nodeCol;
  node({@required this.onPressed});
  GestureTapCallback onPressed;
    @override 
    _nodeState createState() => _nodeState();
     }

   class _nodeState extends State<node> {
     int cnt = 0;
     Color color = Colors.grey;

     change_color(){    
        setState(() {
        int r = widget.nodeRow , c = widget.nodeCol;
        print('$r $c');
        playArea.grid[r][c] +=1;
        playArea.grid[r][c]%=2;
       print(playArea.grid);
       color =  (color == Colors.grey ) ? Colors.black : Colors.grey;
         });
      } 
    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        height: 20,
        width: 20,
        child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => change_color(),
        child: Container(
        color: color,
           ),
         ),
       );
      }
     }


  int totRow = 0;
  class listDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  int rowNum;
  @override
  _listDisplayState createState() => _listDisplayState();
         }

    class _listDisplayState extends State<listDisplay> {
     @override
     double length = colNum.toDouble() * 20;
     double height =  20;
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
          width: length,
         height: height,
         child: new ListView.builder(
         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
         shrinkWrap: true,
         itemCount:colNum ,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt , int Index){
         node curr = new node();
         curr.nodeRow =(currNodeValue/rowNum).toInt();
         curr.nodeCol = currNodeValue - (curr.nodeRow * rowNum);
         currNodeValue++;
         return curr;
            }
          ),
         );
        }
      }

   class GridDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _GridDisplayState createState() => _GridDisplayState();
      }

    class _GridDisplayState extends State<GridDisplay> {
    @override

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Container(
      child: new ListView.builder(
       itemCount: rowNum,
       scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
       itemBuilder:(BuildContext ctxt , int Index){
        return Center(
          child: new listDisplay()
               );
              }
            ),
          );
         }
        }
```

in the main scaffold i will return in the body place : GridDislay()
while creating the GridDisplay -it creates list of ListDisplays And for creation of each ListDisplay it will create List of Nodes.
while creation of each node the 2darray gets mapped via class data members in the node object - Now if the user presses a Node widget on screen then with the class data members nodeRow and nodeCol - the background 2D array gets updated as well.
Now can i control the widgets in reverse order? like can i map the 2d array to the widget ?
if the value in the 2d array gets updated then it should immediately reflect in the gridDisplay widget (of respective Nodes).

Comment: Please add code for easy understanding

Comment: i have added code and detailed explanation.Please help me out.